# VectorPlot3D - vectors starting at points

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization, vector

Normally the vectors in `VectorPlot3D` are attached the middle. How to get them attached at the beginning (what is typical conventions in most textbooks) by use of `VectorPlot3D`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update V.11.3:** In version 11.3+ the new option `VectorMarkers` can be used with `Placed` to control the position of vectors:

```
points = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {2}];    
Row[VectorPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   VectorPoints -> points, VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow" , #], 
   VectorScale -> {.5, .4}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   Prolog -> {Yellow, Opacity[.5], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
      Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points]}] & /@ {"Start", "End"}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can post-process the graphics output to shift the arrows:

```
points = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {2}];

vp1 = VectorPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   VectorPoints -> points, VectorScale -> {.5, .4}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   Prolog -> {Yellow, Opacity[.5], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
             Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points]}];

vp1b = vp1 /. Arrow[x_] :> Arrow[{Mean[x], Mean[x] + Last[x] - First[x]}];
(* or  vp1 /. Arrow[x_] :> Translate[Arrow[x],Mean[x]-First[x]] *)

Row[{vp1, vp1b}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Similarly, for `VectorPlot3D`:

```
points2 =Tuples[{-1, 1}, {3}];

vp2 = VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   VectorPoints -> points2, VectorScale -> .25, ImageSize -> 400];
vp2 = Show[vp2, Graphics3D@{Yellow, Opacity[.5], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
     Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[.03], Sphere[points2, .2]}];
vp2b = vp2 /. Arrow[x_] :> Arrow[{Mean[x], Mean[x] + Last[x] - First[x]}];

Row[{vp2, vp2b}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Update:** A function that shifts the arrows to start from the designated `points`:

```
trF = MapAt[# /. Arrow[x_] :> Arrow[{Mean[x], Mean[x] + Last[x] - First[x]}] &, #, {1}] &;
(* or trF = MapAt[#/.Arrow[x_] :> Translate[Arrow[x],Mean[x]-First[x]]&,#,{1}]&; *)

Row[trF /@ {vp1, vp2}, Spacer[15]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** For `3D` arrow glyphs, we need to modify the replacement rule:

```
vp3 = VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   VectorPoints->points2, VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorScale -> .25, ImageSize -> 400];
vp3 = Show[vp3,  Graphics3D@{Yellow, Opacity[.5], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
     Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[.03], Sphere[points2, .2]}];
vp3b =vp3/. Arrow[Tube[x_, r__]]:>Arrow[Tube[{Mean[x], Mean[x] + Last[x] - First[x]}, r]];

Row[{vp3, vp3b}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: An exhaustive answer with nice figures, thanks.
In my tests the function with Translate[..] appeared to be 40% faster,
is that right ?

Comment: @sebqas, i haven't done any timing test, but it makes sense that `Translate` is faster.