# VectorPlot scaling

Tags: plotting

There must be a simple way to do this, but maybe I'm just dense at this point, I can't seem to achieve it: For a manipulate environment, I need to generate VectorPlots that have a fixed scaling of the vector sizes, so that a vector of length 1, say, always appears at the same size independently of the size of other vectors.

I have a function that, in principle, looks like so:

```
vp[t_] := 
 VectorPlot[{1, x t}, {x, 0, 1.7}, {y, 0, 1.7}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

Thus, the vectors at the left edge (x=0) all have length 1. I want these vectors to appear at the same size no matter what the value of t is.

Right now I get:

[image]

[image]

so the vectors are rescaled so that their maximum size stays the same. I found a discussion of what seems like a similar request [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80864/absolute-vectorplot-scaling), but I'm not entirely sure the question is really the same; in any case, I find it hard to believe there's no simple way to do this. Is there really no simple `VectorScale` directive that does something as straightforward as this, namely saying "a vector of norm `nv` will be plotted at length of `d nv`", where `d` is a length given in terms of plotting units"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may make your vector length a function of `x` using the explict scale form [`VectorScale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorScale.html).

With `VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, 1 + #1 &}` then

```
Table[VectorPlot[{1, x t}, {x, 0, 1.7}, {y, 0, 1.7}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, 1 + #1 &}], {t, {1, 100}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The size can be adjusted by increasing the unit length (e.i. increasing `0.03`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is it `1+#1`? Shouldn't this read `Sqrt[1+#1]`, or `Norm[{1, #1}]`? Remember, I still want the length of the vectors proportional to the magnitude of `{1, x t}`.

Comment: @Pirx Those scale functions will work as well. The object is to have a function of `x` independent of `t` such that the lengths remain constant for each value of `x` as `t` varies. The  scale function does not have to be a vector measure.

Comment: O.k., I think I have it now. Thanks!