# How to change tail position of VectorPlot vectors?

Tags: plotting, options, vector

When I use `VectorPlot[]` to plot a vector field it looks like the vectors are placed with their midpoints at their points of evaluation.  I.e. the vector $\textbf{F}(x,y)$ is positioned with its midpoint at $(x,y)$.

I think it looks more natural when the vectors are placed with their tails at their evaluation points.  Is this possible to change?

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/vectorscale-explanation/73950#73950) is an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Closely related Q/A: [VectorPlot3D - vectors starting at points](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71501/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, this confirms that vectors are placed with their midpoints at their points of evaluation:

```
vp = VectorPlot[
  {y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  VectorPoints -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
  Epilog -> {
    Red, PointSize[Large],
    Point[{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}],
    Green, Point[{{1.214, -0.785}, {0.785, -1.214}}]
    }
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this example we told `VectorPlot` to plot arrows in four specific places. We then plotted red points in those specific places, and as expected the points turned up in the middle of the arrows. Here is how to change it:

```
vp /. Arrow[{pt1_, pt2_}] :> Arrow[
   {pt1, pt2},
   {Norm[pt1 - pt2]/2, -Norm[pt1 - pt2]/2}
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`VectorPlot` generates graphics directives of the form `Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]`. In fact, I got the coordinates for the green points by inspecting the graphics object with `FullForm`. My solution is to replace all expressions of the form `Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]` in the graphics object with a similar expression, utilizing the third argument of `Arrow` to get the desired adjustment.

If you are using `VectorStyle -> "Segment"` to plot lines instead of arrows, you can similarly use

```
vp /. Line[l : {p1 : {_, _}, p2 : {_, _}}] :> With[{m = Mean[l]}, Line[
    {m, m + Normalize[m - p1] Norm[p2 - p1]}
    ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do I do with that piece of code?

Comment: @PGmath Graphics in *Mathematica* are expressions, in the form `Graphics[{...}]` or `Graphics3D[...]`. You can look those two up in the documentation. Plot functions are functions that generate `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` expressions. My solution is a replacement rule that will rewrite the expression, particularly the `Arrow` primitives that `VectorPlot` created. For a great explanation of this concept please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4435720/395258). The short answer is: you take the replacement rule `./ Arrow...` and put it right after `VectorPlot[...]`.

Comment: Is there a version of this that works for `VectorStyle -> "Segment"`?  I tried it this way and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @PGmath That would have been a nice exercise for you, but nevertheless I posted something.

Comment: Thank you.  I did try to monkey with that code a bit but everything I tried either threw an error or didn't do anything.